# Transformation on insertion into PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, srid

If I have a specific SRID set on a geometry column in PostGIS, say 4326; if I then insert geometry with a different SRID, say 4283, what SRID will be stored in the database, will PostGIS transform the geometry to the column SRID on entry or will it just not allow insertion?

`INSERT INTO sometable(geom) VALUES ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-38.2481 141.7370)',4283)`

[image: geometry_columns view]

Comment: It should not be possible to do that. For me `insert into test(wkb_geometry) values (ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-38.2481 141.7370)',4283))` gives `ERROR:  Geometry SRID (4283) does not match column SRID (4326)
SQL state: 22023`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your column is seen as registered in the PostGIS `geometry|geography_columns` system *View* (meaning that its constraints are known in the system relations), the *typemod* constraints of the data type (`GEOMETRY|GEOGRAPHY`) are going to get enforced; if it is set to a specific SRID *typemod*, you **cannot** `INSERT` data that violates that inherent constraint, or `UPDATE` an existing row in that manner.